Autoroute nested-routing failed to navigate to sub-page
I have been using Autoroute and there's a point where im really confused... I know that for sub routes the path must be without "/" this is my current routing setup:
@AutoRouterConfig(
  generateForDir: [
    'lib/ui/router',
    'lib/ui/splash',
    'lib/ui/authentication',
    'lib/ui/authentication/login',
    'lib/ui/authentication/signup',
    'lib/ui/loader',
    'lib/ui/dashboard',
    'lib/ui/stage',
    'lib/ui/workout_detail',
    'lib/ui/settings',
    'lib/ui/not_found',
    'lib/ui/videoplayer',
  ],
)
class HealerRouter extends RootStackRouter {
  HealerRouter({bool isAuthenticated = false})
      : _isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
  final bool _isAuthenticated;
  @override
  RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.adaptive();

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: EmptyShellRoute(
            ScreensEnum.splash.path,
          ),
          path: ScreensEnum.splash.path,
          usesPathAsKey: true,
          keepHistory: false,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              page: Splash.page,
              path: '',
              usesPathAsKey: true,
              keepHistory: false,
              guards: [AuthGuard(authenticated: _isAuthenticated)],
            ),
            authenticationRoute,
            AutoRoute(
              page: Loader.page,
              path: ScreensEnum.loader.lastSegment,
              usesPathAsKey: true,
              keepHistory: false,
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              page: Dashboard.page,
              path: ScreensEnum.dashboard.lastSegment,
              usesPathAsKey: true,
              children: [
                stageTab,
                settingsTab,
              ],
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              path: ScreensEnum.workoutDetail.noInitSlashJoinSegments(2),
              page: Workout_detail.page,
              children: [
                AutoRoute(
                  path: 'videoplayer',
                  page: Videoplayer.page,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ];
}

and this is the enum with the paths definitions:
enum ScreensEnum {
  splash('/'),
  authentication('/authentication'),
  login('/authentication/login'),
  signup('/authentication/signup'),
  loader('/loader'),
  dashboard('/dashboard'),
  stage('/dashboard/stage'),
  workoutDetailHolder('/workout_detail'),
  workoutDetail('/workout_detail/:param'),
  workoutVideo('/workout_detail/:param/videoplayer'),
  settings('/dashboard/settings'),
  notFound('/not-found');

  const ScreensEnum(this.path);

  final String path;

  static List<String> get unauthorizedRoutes =>
      [splash.path, authentication.path, login.path, signup.path];

  String get lastSegment => path.split('/').last;

  String noInitSlashJoinSegments(int count) =>
      path.split('/').sublist(1, count + 1).join('/');
}

When I try to access directly into workout_detail it works fine. since im going from stageTab into workoutDetail, but if I try to go into workoutVideo, the route goes directly to workoutDetail again. Im not sure what's the issue...
Thanks for any advice.
